# vba filling a dynamic array with strings

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

hey I'm new to vba and I already tried searching for an answer to my question.
I want to fill a dynamic array with specific arrays which can be changed in the table. for that I created the following code:

```
Sub ZellenArrayReader()
    Dim boom() As Variant
    Dim rowsboom As Integer
    Dim sh As Variant

    sh = "TAB1"
    Worksheets(sh).Range("A1").Select
    rowsboom = Selection.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2

    ReDim boom(0 To rowsboom)

    For i = LBound(boom) To i = UBound(boom)
        boom(i) = Worksheets(sh).Cells(i + 2, 1)
    Next i

    Cells(10, 5).FormulaR1C1 = boom(0)
    Cells(10, 1).FormulaR1C1 = boom(1)

End Sub
```

The for part is the on ewhich is not working correctly. It runs the code just one even if the Upperbound of the array is 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `For ... Next` loop to:

```
For i = LBound(boom) To UBound(boom)
    boom(i) = Worksheets(sh).Cells(i+2, 1)
Next i
```

Comment: omg it was such a stupid mistake, thank you very much , now it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Small modification, It work well.

```
Private Sub ZellenArrayReader()

    Dim boom() As Variant
    Dim rowsboom As Integer
    Dim sh As String

    sh = "TAB1"

    Sheets(sh).Range("A1").Select

    rowsboom = Selection.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2

    ReDim boom(0 To rowsboom)

    For i = 0 To UBound(boom) Step 1
        boom(i) = Sheets(sh).Cells(i + 2, 1)
    Next i

    Cells(10, 5).FormulaR1C1 = boom(0)
    Cells(10, 1).FormulaR1C1 = boom(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm so much in Java that this mistake happened, Thank you very much :D

Comment: If it is work, accept an answer for the question. You are welcome..!

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, the `i=UBound(boom)` part of your for loop is causing the problem. If boom had 1 element, that would return True(i=0 and UBound(boom)=0) and it would be like `For i = LBound(boom) to -1` (True is -1 when cast as a Long). That would loop zero times. In your case, you have at least two elements, so `i=UBound(boom)` returns False. That's like `For i = LBound(boom) to 0` which is why it only executes once.

The `Range.Value` property returns a two dimensional array and is generally faster than looping through an array and filling it with values from cells. The lower bound of an array assigned via `Range.Value` is 1, not zero. Here's a rewrite of the code without the loop.

```
Sub ZellenArrayReader()

    Dim vBoom As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rCurrReg As Range

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TAB1")

    Set rCurrReg = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    vBoom = rCurrReg.Resize(rCurrReg.Rows.Count - 2).Value

    sh.Cells(10, 5).Value = vBoom(1, 1)
    sh.Cells(10, 1).Value = vBoom(2, 1)

End Sub
```